# Cannot setState Variable

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I used setState to update the 2 states in my program. My console.log was able to display the 2 updated states. However, the setState method doesn't work. The two variables age and gender remain empty and does not render in my jsx. Thanks in advance for your help

```
this.state={ age: '', gender: '' }........ //this.state provided


  fetchUserProfile(){
const { currentUser } = firebaseApp.auth();
firebaseApp.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/profile`).orderByValue()
.on('child_added', snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.val()); //successfully shows age and gender on console
    this.setState({
      age: snapshot.val().age,                 //does not update the state of age and gender
      gender: snapshot.val().gender
    })
})
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Are you binding your fetchUserProfile function?

If not just change:

`fetchUserProfile(){` to `fetchUserProfile = () => {`

Comment: hi Matt, i tried to add the bind function to the constructor but it doesn't work. I have also tried fetchUserProfile=()=> but no success also.  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
      name: '',
      mobile: '',
      email: '',
      date: '',
      age: '',
      gender: ''
    },
    this.fetchUserProfile = this.fetchUserProfile.bind(this)
  }

Comment: To test if its working, if you change age and gender inside setState to like age: 10, gender: 'male'. Does it work?

Comment: hi matt, when i change age and gender inside setState method to age: 10 and gender: 'male', it still doesn't work.